# How to get insertions for unix-style wildcards in python?

Tags: python, glob

I have a somewhat complicated file-structure.
Using `glob.glob('base_directory/*/*/*<some_pattern>.dat')` I do get a list of all the relevant filenames, but I would need to work with the names of the relevant subdirectories on the different levels, so what I really want are just the insertions for the wildcards.

In the end I would like to build a dictionary of dictionaries for the insertions at each sub-level of my file structure. But for a start I only need a function / package that returns only the insertions of the pattern-matching. Any ideas where to find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm reading the question correctly, you can get all the matching paths with `pathlib.Path.glob`:

```bash
pushd /tmp
mkdir -p a/b/c/d/1.dat
mkdir -p a/b/e/g/2.dat
mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/g.dat
```

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> files = list(Path("/tmp").glob("**/*.dat"))
>>> print(files)
[PosixPath('/tmp/a/b/e/g/2.dat'), PosixPath('/tmp/a/b/c/d/1.dat'), PosixPath('/tmp/a/b/c/d/e/g.dat')]
```

See [the pathlib docs on glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=iterdir#pathlib.Path.glob) for more details.  There's also [`.rglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=iterdir#pathlib.Path.rglob) which effectively saves typing `**`.

### Extracting parts

Apparently you want something like groups (`()`) in regexs. Whilst there's no support for that in `pathlib.glob` of which I'm aware, for the particular example you gave it's easy enough to get it:

```py
import re

def analyse_path(p: Path) -> tuple[str]:
    _*, a, b, c, fn = p.parts
    match_ = re.search("param1_([0-9]+)-param2_(.+).dat", fn)
    if not match_:
        raise ValueError(f"unable to extract data from {fn}") 
    return (a, b, c, *match_.groups())

useful_data = [analyse_path(p) for p in Path("/tmp").glob("*/*/*/*.dat")]
```

The idea here is to use the glob to narrow down and the do a regex search on the filename itself.  But if you need to do anything more complicated than '*' in the glob, I would just do the whole thing with a regex, probably operating on the result of `Path(basedir).glob("**")`.  If you have very large dirs or lots of irrelevant files you'll likely hit a bottlneck here, but profile before you try anything less clear than a big glob.

Comment: You could also use Path.rglob

Comment: @jakub yep.  added, but I personally prefer an explicit `**` as it's more obvious to me what it does.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not exactly what I want: I do not need the pathnames but the characters that are inserted. Maybe I was too generic: The naming of the sub-directories and the files encodes some characteristic properties that I need to work with, so I would like to know, for instance,what insertions have made prior to a certain sequence of letters somewhere in the filepaths. Working with a list of filenames and then writing a routine for the analysis the strings on each sublevel feels too cumbersome...

Comment: @Dididombi how complicated are your globs?  It sounds like you want something like `re` only with unix-globs and on filenames.  If you can cope with regex syntax I'd just use `re` on a list of *all* the files.  It would be handy if you could update the q with what glob exactly you're using---if you just want the dirnames it's easy enough.